# tried to build an image but I am keep getting this error. I clone many projects from public GitHub and have the same issue

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose, dockerfile

[+] Building 14.6s (1/1) FINISHED

=> ERROR [internal] booting buildkit                                                                             14.6s

=> => pulling image moby/buildkit:buildx-stable-1                                                                12.7s

=> => creating container buildx_buildkit_default                                                                  1.9s

------

\> [internal] booting buildkit:

------

Error response from daemon: crun: creating cgroup directory `/sys/fs/cgroup/systemd/docker/buildx/libpod-86ba89f2fa100371f55620a538087d7e63a80541ae3b69b4919483f52ff616fa`: No such file or directory: OCI runtime attempted to invoke a command that was not found

`docker-compose` process finished with exit code 17

```
# Docker Compose file Reference (https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/)

version: '3'

# Define services
services:

  # App Service
  app:
    # Configuration for building the docker image for the service
    build:
      context: . # Use an image built from the specified dockerfile in the current directory.
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080" # Forward the exposed port 8080 on the container to port 8080 on the host machine
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on: 
      - redis # This service depends on redis. Start that first.
    environment: # Pass environment variables to the service
      REDIS_URL: redis:6379    
    networks: # Networks to join (Services on the same network can communicate with each other using their name)
      - backend

  # Redis Service   
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine" # Use a public Redis image to build the redis service    
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - backend

networks:
  backend:
```

Comment: What's your system?

Comment: windows. I tried simple public project from github and run the docker-compose file same error.

Comment: Is docker up to date? Have you tried reinstalling docker?

Comment: yes, it's up to date i have reinstalled many times. Didn't get any solution from that

Comment: This question has been around for a while, did you figure it out in the meantime?